# GAS: Save file in folder

Tags: google-apps-script

GAS: I succesfully created a file with DocumentApp.create and saved it in my Drive root using saveAndClose(). What I'm trying to do is to save the file in MyFolder that exists in Drive root.

I am able to create a file in this folder using createFile() but I'd like to create it using DocumentApp.create, so that I can format the text. Is this possible somehow? If not is it possible to copy a file from root to MyFolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [File.addToFolder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#addToFolder)